# Android Tabs in XML

Tags: android, xml, tabs

My question is simple.  Is it possible to create tabs entirely in xml?  My app has only one activity.  I want to have 2 tabs that show the same data but in slightly different layouts.  It seems like it should be but I cannot find anything on it.

TIA,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. Your layout for each tab would go inside a tabwidget. This will have it's limitations that you would easily get around if you employ a simple TabHost

```
 <TabHost 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- Tabs at bottom of screen -->
    <TabWidget
    android:background="@drawable/textview_top"
    android:layout_weight="12"
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    />
   </TabHost>
```

Comment: @codeHammer Don't forget the closing </TabHost> tag at the end. I had it pasted in the code blcok above, but it is not showing up.

Comment: Hidden part is displayed. You just need to push it by inserting some spaces.